# Change shortcuts of pidgin

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, pidgin

In pidgin, I would like to change the keyboard shortcut of sending messages from <kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIbindkeystrokestomenuitems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [the answer directly above the FAQ entry](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoImakeEntermakeanewlineandCtrlEntersend) in mbnoimi's answer is the one you want.

> #### How do I make Enter make a newline and Ctrl+Enter send?
>
> Locate or create your gtkrc-2.0 file and insert:
>
> ```
> binding "my-bindings"
> {
>     bind "Return" { "insert-at-cursor" ("\n") }
>     bind "<ctrl>Return" { "message_send" () }
> }
> widget "*pidgin_conv_entry" binding "my-bindings"
> ```